# Delta function question

Tags: functional-equations, distribution-theory

Given the functions
$$f(x)= \delta (x-a)$$ 
$$g(x)= \frac{1}{a} \delta \left(x- \frac{1}{a}\right)$$ 
for a real constant $a\gt0$, is there a relationship between $f$ and $g$?

I believe that $ g\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=af(x) $, but I'm not $100\%$ sure. I have used the properties of $\delta (f(x))$ with $f(x)= \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{a}$, which has the only root $x=a$, but I do not know what else to do in order to prove it.

Comment: $ \delta (-a)=0= \delta (\infty-a) $ and $ f(a)= \infty = g(1/a) $

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
g\left(\frac1x\right)=\frac1a\delta\left(\frac1x-\frac1a\right)=\frac1a\delta(x-a)\left|\left[\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\frac1x-\frac1a\right)\right]_{x=a}\right|^{-1}=a\delta(x-a)=af(x)\;.
$$

Comment: I don't see, what motivates the second $=$?

Comment: @draks: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_distribution#Composition_with_a_function

Comment: Interesting, thanks, +1...